# Manage iPhone app both offline and online

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I am stuck to a point, I am managing my app offline also.. first time i get all data (images) from a webservices and store its path into sqlite, now I take an int value 0 or 1 and store its state into `NSUserDefaults` now I am facing problem in updating those images, like if images are changed how should I notify into my app, I searched it on Google and only solution is to send push notification to app when record is updated. What if user do not allow push notification?

Is there any other solution to manage app offline and update only when record is changed from online database?

Comment: you can find descriptive answer from here. "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35473393/manage-iphone-app-both-online-and-offline/35595362#35595362"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sync your Data  with server Periodically , like  call a webservice which check if images have been changed then fetch the new images and if images are not changed then continue with old data.You can add a Boolean Value on server end which can tell you if data on server is updated or not or you can check this with Time stamp like when data is updated last time then compare your local time with Server time at which data has been updated . Good Luck !!

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to handle such kind of situation:

1. Use push notifications which is the best solution for such situation.
2. Query the server periodically by giving the ability to the user to set the time interval from app settings.
3. Query the server whenever the app came from background to foreground.

Comment: if user did not allow push notification? i mentioned in question

Comment: @AliMajeed then you can get the updates from the server using point no. 3. Even if you can use Facebook app it also handle the data like this. Just try to off the notification for Facebook and run the app you will get the updates.

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to use BackgroundFetch to update the app content while it is not running. I am using similar fetch for one of my apps where I update the content before the user opens the app. I am fetching a small list of items that is indicating which one is up to date and which is not. Then, at runtime I present an option to the user to manually update these items, but of course you can also download all that while in backgroundfetch. My app is without network reach most of the time, and backgroundFetch will update the items list first thing when there is some internet connection.

There are two important methods here that you need to register, *setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:* and *application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:* . You can read more about them in Apples guides for background modes.

You can also check out this good tutorial about this fetching capability: http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/

Answer (score 0):

There is way which has being most popular as most of peoples are preferring

- At server side build mechanism, which can send lists of images updated after particular date/time.
- To keep track of last sync date/time at locally.
- Pinged on server with last date/time in case of first time pass any past date and check for update, if there is then download updated images, Otherwise.

**Now you have to decide this process when would be query to server**

1) At every first time application will be load. (At `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`).
2) Query the server periodically by giving the ability to the user to set the time interval from app settings or else where would be preferable.
3) Query the server whenever the app came from **background** to **foreground**.